# Get client IP adress trough Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I have a Heroku app with Cloudflare and I try to display a different version according to the localization of the client.
It works well in developpment but it's not the case in production (the `/en` is always displayed, not the `/fr`).
I use the express-ip npm package.

The code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const expressip = require("express-ip");

router.use(expressip().getIpInfoMiddleware);

router.get("/", function ipFrance(req, res) {
  const ipInfo = req.ipInfo;
  const ipInfoRegion = req.ipInfo.region;
  const ipInfoCountry = req.ipInfo.country;

  //var message = `Hey, you are browsing from ${ipInfoRegion}, ${ipInfoCountry}`;
  if(ipInfoCountry == "FR" || ipInfoRegion == "Wallonia") {
      res.redirect("/fr");
  } else {
      res.redirect("/en");
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't offer translations based on IP address. [There's an HTTP header for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language), and an express API method [`req.acceptsLanguages()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.acceptsLanguages) which uses that header:

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  if (req.acceptsLanguages("fr")) {
    res.redirect("/fr");
  } else {
    res.redirect("/en");
  }
});
```

Some French-native people may like browsing in English, and other parts of the world may prefer to browse in French. Let them make that decision, don't make it for them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nswer ! Yeah, I'd like to choose the language automatically but the user can choose it by himself  quite directly after that